# How to create groupings of constants similar to "dynamic enumerations" in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

What are my options for declaring a grouping of constants from multiple libraries in Java?

For example, I have a network message protocol.  The protocol has some standard messages and allows for the creation of custom messages.  Each message has a unique ID number.  I would really like to combine all these unique IDs into an enumeration in my application.  Something like...

```
public enum MessageType
{
    //Standard messages in one library
    FooMsg(1),
    BarMsg(2),

    //Custom messages in another library
    MyCustomMessage(100),
    MyOthercustomMessage(101);

    private long msgNumber;
    public long getMessageNumber(long msgNumber) { return msgNumber;}

    public static MessageType fromMessageNumber(long messageNumber)
    {
    //Reverse lookup code here...
    }

    //Few more utilities that don't matter for this question

    private MessageType(long msgNumber)
    {
        this.msgNumber = msgNumber;
    }
}
```

Then I can make methods that are generic for a message type.

```
public void doStuff(MessageType msgType, MyMessageObject data)
{
   switch(msgType)
   {
      case FooMsg: //Do stuff
       break;
    //Other stuff
   }
}
```

However, an enumeration requires that I know all of the message types at compile time but the messages are spread across multiple libraries.  Some of these libraries are loaded optionally, so if they're not loaded I do not want to include them in the enumeration.

Is there a way I can define a "collection of constants" at run time that function similarly to an enumeration?

Comment: Use a `Map` of some sort, maybe? Key = name, value = constant value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with an `enum`, but is there any reason that a simple `Map` wouldn't serve your purposes? Or, since you have some other utility methods, a class backed by a Map? You could add only those messages for libraries that have been loaded, and if there is a clear delineation between the loading phase and run phase of your application, you could even use a builder pattern and freeze the Map as an immutable map, so that once the application was running no further changes could be made to the messages.

(This could be done with either `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` or one of the immutable map types from Guava.)

One thing that is not entirely clear to me is whether you are guaranteed that there will be no collisions in the messages used by different libraries. That could be a concern.

For example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MessageType {
    private final static Map<Long, MessageType> messageTypes = new HashMap<>();

    // it isn't clear how the libraries would provide information on
    // the message types they support; suppose that each library has a
    // MessageInfo that implements Map<Long, String> with all its types:
    public static void loadLibrary(MessageInfo messageInfo) {
        // populate the map with each message type it supports
        for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : messageInfo.entrySet()) {
            MessageType messageType =
                new MessageType(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            messageTypes.put(entry.getKey(), messageType);
        }
    }

    // A MessageType has a name and a number
    private final long number;
    private final String name;

    private MessageType(long number, String name) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getMessageNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getMessageName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static MessageType fromMessageNumber(long number) {
        if (!messageTypes.containsKey(number)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown message: " + number);
        }
        return messageTypes.get(number);
    }
}
```

You could also add checks to make sure a duplicate message type was not defined, that a message type with a `null` name or number wasn't created, and add `hashCode()`, `equals(Object)`, and `toString()` methods that depended upon the name and number. For instance,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "message:" + name + "<" + number + ">";
}
```

Or however you wanted the messages to appear for debugging purposes. Note that because only one MessageType object is created for each message type, it should be safe to compare them with `==`, although you don't get the strong protections that you get from the Java `enum` type. (It would still be possible to create duplicate `MessageType` objects by either reflection, or, if you made them `Serializable`, by serializing and deserializing one.) (This approach, where only one instance for each distinct value is created, is known as the *Flyweight* design pattern, as you may know.)

Comment: I'm not worried about the backing data structure. Yes, I'm guaranteed no collisions on names or message ID numbers.  My goal is to preserve the ability to keep compilation protection so I can do things like "void doStuff(MessageType msgType)" instead of "void doStuff(int msgType)."

Comment: Well, you could do that with a value class backed by a Map. The value class would be the type you would use as a parameter, and the Map would be used e.g., by its `valueOf` method that would parse a number into an instance of the value class for you. I'll give you an example of what I mean.

Comment: No need for an example, I know what you mean.  Thanks!